# upgrading identity from .net core 1.1 to 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I had the following code which worked at 1.1.

```
 public static IServiceCollection RegisterRepositoryServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>>(
                config => { config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                    config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                    config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie";
                    config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticAuthenticate = false;
                    config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
                    {
                        OnRedirectToLogin = async ctx =>
                        {
                            if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/visualjobs") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                            {
                                ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                            }
                            await Task.Yield();
                        }
                    };
                }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<VisualJobsDbContext, int>()
              .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<VisualJobsDbContext>();

            services.AddScoped<IRecruiterRepository, RecruiterRepository>();
            services.AddSingleton<IAccountRepository, AccountRepository>();

            return services;
        }
```

It now doesn't like the section that makes reference to the config.Cookies....

I've been searching the net, but I cant really find anything to replace this.

Comment: _It now doesn't like the section that makes reference to the config.Cookies...._ is a very vague problem description. Can you elaborate? Do you get compile errors?

Comment: There are no more 4 different cookie configurations, just a single one. Please read [the announcements on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/262)

Comment: @MartinLiversage no it doesn't compile in VS2017 it red lines and just says that it's obsolete

Comment: @bilpor: I have added a note in my answer below with regard to the AutomaticAuthenticate option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `AddIdentity` to add the cookie authentication services and then configure the settings using `ConfigureApplicationCookie` as follows:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>>(config => {
        config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    })
.AddUserStore<UserStore<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>, VisualJobsDbContext, int>>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o => {
    o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
    o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
    {
        OnRedirectToLogin = async ctx =>
        {
            if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/visualjobs") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            }
            else
            {
                ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
            }
            await Task.Yield();
        }
    };
});
```

In addition, in your `Configure()` method, remember to call the following:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Additional reading:
[Migrating Authentication and Identity to ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x)

**Note:**
The following section in this article regards the `AutomaticAuthenticate` option:

> **Setting Default Authentication Schemes**
>
> In 1.x, the `AutomaticAuthenticate` and `AutomaticChallenge`
>   properties of the [AuthenticationOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.AuthenticationOptions?view=aspnetcore-1.1) base class were intended to
>   be set on a single authentication scheme. There was no good way to
>   enforce this. In 2.0, these two properties have been removed as
>   properties on the individual `AuthenticationOptions` instance. They
>   can be configured in the `AddAuthentication` method call within the
>   `ConfigureServices` method of Startup.cs:
>
> `services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);`